# Expected Volume of Convex Hull of Spherical Normal Distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, variance, convex-hulls

I would like some input on if my understanding and solution to the following problem is correct:

Given a spherical normal distribution $N(\mu, \Sigma)$ of dimension $d$ with:

$$\Sigma = \left[
               \begin{array}{cccc}
                 \sigma_1 ^2 & 0 & \dots & 0\\
                 0 & \sigma_2 ^2 & \dots & 0 \\
                 \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
                 0 & 0 & \dots & \sigma_d ^2
               \end{array}
           \right]
\qquad \sigma = \sigma_1 = \dots = \sigma_d $$

We select $n$ variables $K_n = \{X_1, \dots, X_n\}$ with each $X_i \sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$ independent and identically distributed from this distribution, and wish to calculate the expected volume of the convex hull $E[Vol(K_n)]$.

From F. Affentranger's work (http://www.seminariomatematico.unito.it/rendiconti/cartaceo/49-3/359.pdf) in 1991 we have that if $N(\mu, \Sigma) = N(0, 1)$ is the standard spherical normal distribution of unit variance in dimension $d$, then the expected volume of the convex hull of $n$ random points selected from this distribution is:

$$E[Vol(K_n)] = \kappa_d (\log n)^{d / 2} (1 + o(1))$$

where $\kappa_d$ is the volume of the $d$-dimensional unit ball.

Given that arbitrary normal distributions $N(\mu, \sigma ^2)$ can be reduced to the standard normal distribution $N(0, 1)$ by the relation:

$$ N(\mu, \sigma ^2) = \sigma N(0, 1) + \mu $$

Is my understanding correct when I claim that it follows that the convex hull of $n$ randomly selected points $K_n$ from an arbitrary spherical normal distribution $N(\mu, \Sigma)$ with $\Sigma_{i, i} = \sigma^2, \Sigma_{i, j, i \neq j} = 0$ would be:

$$
\begin{align*}
    E[Vol(K_n)] &= E\big[Vol(\{X_1, \dots, X_n\})\big] \\
                &= E\big[Vol(\{\sigma N(0, 1)_1 + \mu, \dots, \sigma N(0, 1)_n + \mu\}) \big] \\
                &= E\big[ Vol( \{ \sigma N(0, 1)_1, \dots, \sigma N(0, 1)_n \}) \big] \\
                &= \sigma^d E\big[ Vol( \{ N(0, 1)_1, \dots, N(0, 1)_n \}) \big] \\
                &= \sigma^d \big[\kappa_d (\log n)^{d / 2} (1 + o(1)) \big]
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: I would expect to see some way $det(\Sigma)$ figuring in this formula if the off-diagonal entries are non-zero. Note that $\sigma^d$ is essentially the determinant in the diagonal case.

Comment: In fact, look up on literature known as whitening transformation. If you multiply every such random vector by $\Sigma^{-1/2}$, it goes back to the unit-variance Gaussian distribution. Thus, the expected volume of that should be $\det(\Sigma^{-1/2})$*(expected volume of unit variance spherical distribution) which is already given. Probably someone else here can verify this.

Comment: Thanks, edited the post to clarify iid condition of all the random variables.